# Solving a separable differential equation with limits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider this equation, where $a$,$b$ and $k$ are constants,

**$$\frac{dy}{dt} = k(a-y)(b-y)$$**

Assuming an initial condition $y=0$ at $t=0$

1. Solve this equation for $y(t)$ for the case $a=b$.
2. Solve this equation for the case $0 \lt a \lt b$
3. By considering the limit $b \rightarrow a$ in 2) show that the two results are consistent with each other.

So I am confident with my result for (i), through separating the variables, integrating then finding the constant of integration by using the initial conditions, resulting in:

**$$y(t) = -\frac{1}{kt}$$**

However I am confused as to how to solve for the case of limits ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you got the right solution for the first point? If $a=b$ then the equation is $dy/dx = k(a-y)^2$ and by separation of variables I get $y(x) = a^2kx/(akx+1)$.

Comment: For $b \neq a$ you can use the partial fraction decomposition $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(a-y)(b-y)} = \frac{1}{b-a} \left( \frac{1}{a-y} - \frac{1}{b-y} \right)$. After finding the general solution take the limit as $b \rightarrow a$.

Comment: @Gibbs apologies, the post had been edited, it is dy/dt not dy/dx

Comment: The name of the variable does not matter. Actually now I read $dy/dx$ in the first equation and $t=0$ as initial data. There is no consistency in the notation. Anyway, I suggest you try again to compute the solution in the first case.

Comment: Something is definitely wrong here. The solution should depend on $a$, and your solution is not $0$ at $t=0$. Please show your work so we can identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is not correct. If you plug $y = -\frac{1}{kt}$ into the ODE you get

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{1}{kt^2} = ky^2 \ne k(a-y)^2 $$

Furthermore, the initial condition $y(0)=0$ isn't satisfied.

I'll add more to this, if you edit the post to show your own working.